# subversion merge - "has different repository root than"

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I'm working on a relatively new project using Subversion. I've already branched off a couple of times and merged that branch back to trunk with no problems. However, my latest merge is failing - and it seems to be tied into the fact that I added a new file to the branch that does not yet exist on the trunk (in this case, GradientView.h).

Here's what I saw when I tried to merge from the command line:

```
bpapa@mycompany$ svn --username bpapa --password mypassword merge -r 177:HEAD svn://mycompany.server/opt/my-svn-repository/myproject/branches/version-1.4
C    Classes/MyAppDelegate.m
svn: Copyfrom-url 'svn://mycompany.server/opt/my-svn-repository/myproject/branches/version-1.4/Classes/GradientView.h' has different repository root than 'svn://bpapa@mycompany.server'
```

If I look the .svn directory in my working copy and check the "entries" file as a sanity check the repository URL seems to be right - svn://bpapa@mycompany.server/opt/my-svn-repository/myproject/trunk

Another thing to note, if it it helps, is that I was expecting many more files to get merged. It seems to merge the first file (MyAppDelegate), then when it gets to the new file, GradientView.h, it chokes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are  using a non-matching  merge URL:

```
svn://mycompany.server
```

vs.

```
svn://bpapa@mycompany.server
```

try:

```
svn --password mypassword merge -r 177:HEAD svn://bpapa@mycompany.server/opt/my-svn-repository/myproject/branches/version-1.4
```

Comment: Well that was easy. Odd though, as it worked for an earlier merge.

Comment: Whether or not the user ID is in the svn URL is an easy thing to not notice.  

I'm not sure what's going on with the apparent behavior of merging (with conflicts) the first file.  That's odd.